# Authentication Server to server GCP interconnect

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jwt, google-kubernetes-engine, api-key, google-cloud-interconnect

I have an infrastructure in Google cloud, my api in Kubernetes Engine and an external server connected through interconnect, I wanted to know what is the best way to authenticate this external server in my system (GKE).

Using APIKeys would be safe enough?

Answer (score 1):

This [page](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/oidc) explains how to configure an external identity provider to authenticate into Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) clusters and also go through this [link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/api-server-authentication) how to use api-server-authentication.